# Why performance difference in MySQL for where vs join clause

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

- There is huge execution time gap between this three query. I dont know underlying working of MySQL query engine.

**Query1:**

```
select t2.* from (
    select id1, id2 
    from table t2
    where condition
) t3, table t2
where 
t2.id1 = t3.id1 AND
t2.id2 = t3.id2
```

- takes ~180 seconds to run.

**Query2:**

```
select t2.* from (
    select id1, id2 
    from table t2
    where condition
) t3 inner join table t2
on 
t2.id1 = t3.id1 AND
t2.id2 = t3.id2
```

- takes ~180 seconds to run.
- result of explain.

```
id|select_type|table     |partitions|type|possible_keys|key        |key_len|ref                                                                                     |rows |filtered|Extra                                             |
--|-----------|----------|----------|----|-------------|-----------|-------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|-----|--------|--------------------------------------------------|
 1|PRIMARY    |t2        |          |ALL |             |           |       |                                                                                        |95619|      19|Using where                                       |
 1|PRIMARY    |t2        |          |ALL |             |           |       |                                                                                        |95619|       1|Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)|
 1|PRIMARY    |<derived3>|          |ref |<auto_key0>  |<auto_key0>|216    |t2.id1,t2.id2                                                                           |   10|     100|Using index                                       |
 3|DERIVED    |t3        |          |ALL |             |           |       |                                                                                        |95619|     100|Using temporary; Using filesort                   |
```

**Query3:**

```
select t2.* from (
    select id1, id2 
    from table t2
    where condition
) t3 left join table t2
on 
t2.id1 = t3.id1 AND
t2.id2 = t3.id2
```

- takes ~1.6 seconds to run.
- result of explain.

```
id|select_type|table     |partitions|type|possible_keys|key        |key_len|ref                                                                                     |rows |filtered|Extra                                             |
--|-----------|----------|----------|----|-------------|-----------|-------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|-----|--------|--------------------------------------------------|
 1|PRIMARY    |t2        |          |ALL |             |           |       |                                                                                        |95619|      19|Using where                                       |
 1|PRIMARY    |<derived3>|          |ref |<auto_key0>  |<auto_key0>|216    |t2.id1,t2.id2                                                                           |   10|     100|Using index                                       |
 1|PRIMARY    |t2        |          |ALL |             |           |       |                                                                                        |95619|     100|Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)|
 3|DERIVED    |t3        |          |ALL |             |           |       |                                                                                        |95619|     100|Using temporary; Using filesort                   |
```

**UPDATE:** I have edited the question with additional query.
**UPDATE2** Added `Explain` result for query.
**EDIT** : Some stats about table.
subquery contains `83 rows`. `Table t2` have `~97k rows.`

Comment: 1 is an inner join, 2 is a left join

Comment: @EugenRieck That will not matter much because table 1 is subset of table 2. And also i updated the query a bit.

Comment: To the contrary, if left joining to table1 and table1 is a subset of table2, then the left join will be faster than full join because it has less records to process

Comment: Go MySQL!  I would figure that these would get the same execution plan.  But MySQL seems to have a preference for proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.  And that should be your preference as well.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thats what i thout untill i found this weird behavior (atlease for me bacause of lack of understading). `Inner join` is taking as much time as `where`, on the other hand `left join` is way to fast.

Comment: Please provide the number of rows in tables t2 and t3

Comment: @DmitryS Updated question

Comment: Instead of guessing you should take a look at the execution plans. Run the commands with `EXPLAIN`

Comment: LEFT JOIN will force the table order in the execution plan. You should get the same with STRAIGHT_JOIN.

Comment: @Poojan, you should try analyzing table t2 (ANALYZE TABLE t2) - optimizer is clearly choosing an incorrect path. If that doesn't help you can use the suggestion provided by Paul Spiegel.

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for each of your queries.  It may help us explain why you see the timing diffs.  Also `SHOW CREATE TABLE t2`.

Comment: This is interesting. In my experience, LEFT JOIN is usually slower than INNER JOIN, but it's the opposite here.

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: @Barmar, 83 rows left joined to 97k rows will likely be fast, but 83 rows inner joined to 97k rows - that depends on optimizer

Comment: Do you have indexes on `t2.id1` and `t2.id2`? Even better would be a composite index on both columns.

Answer (score 2):

I think what's going on is this:

The first two queries are completely equivalent -- MySQL doesn't distinguish between `INNER JOIN` and cross product when the conditions relating the two tables are the same; it doesn't matter whether the conditions are in `ON` or `WHERE`. So the relevant difference is just between inner join and outer join.

When performing any kind of join, MySQL has to decide which table to treat as the primary table and which is the dependent table. It will scan the primary table and then find the matching rows in the dependent table to produce the result set.

An outer join forces a particular ordering to this; in a `LEFT JOIN`, the left table is always the primary, because the result has to include at least one row for each row in that table. So after generating an intermediate table for `t3`, it just has to scan those 83 rows and find the corresponding rows in `t2` that match the joining condition. The columns being matched are presumably indexed, so this is very fast.

But with an inner join, it can go either way. The query optimizer will try to estimate which table is smaller, and use that as the primary that it scans. But when it's the result of a subquery, it doesn't know how many rows it will return. So it's apparently choosing to use `t2` as the primary, rather than the intermediate `t3` table. This means it's scanning 97K rows, testing each of them to find the matching rows in `t3`.

A smart optimizer would notice that the subquery is simply filtering the same table, so it *must* return fewer rows. Few people would claim that MySQL has one of the better query planners. I suspect it's choosing to use the regular table rather than the intermediate table because it can confine the scan to the index.

It's actually surprising that it only takes 180 seconds, rather than 1800 seconds (30 minutes), which is closer to the ratio between 97k and 83.

I'm not really an expert on interpreting `EXPLAIN` results, but I think you can see the difference on line 2; in the fast case it's `table = <derived3>, rows = 10`, in the slow case it's `table = t2, rows = 95619`.

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you. I also added `Explain` results. And i can relate your answer with that. It has something to do with order of table. I am unable to fully understand EXPLAIN log but its something to consider for this.